# How to debug multiple dependant php files in a browser?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I am new to PHP and Laravel.

I am quite confused about debugging such application. I've set up idea IDE and xdebug, installed Laravel plugin, run apache server, etc.

Right now i have this line of code in my /App/MaterialDivider.php

```
$provision = \Config::get('constants.MARKET_PROVISION');
```

and this in my \config\constants.php

```
return [ 'MARKET_PROVISION' => 0.3 ];
```

When I run artisan commands in my vagrant homestead box, this way of calling constants works within my seeder file. The problem is that I don't know how to make Laravel work when I run single file in a browser.

Apart from that, a simple

```
dd($var)
```

doesn't work either.

When working with multiple files that contain dependant classes, is it necessary to include them? Or should using 'use' be enough? Or is editing composer.json (maybe autoload-dev section?) the right choice?

So far I've been programming in C(++), so this is all very new for me, please be patient.

Partialy **[SOLVED]**. To anyone having similar problems: namespaces are the thing, you might be looking for.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you run single file in a browser?  What file are you trying to run exactly and how are you running it?

Comment: Basically making IDE start browser and navigate to localhost:80/app/MaterialDivider.php. But maybe I am doing it completely wrong, idk.

Comment: Yeah, when you get some time, look into the front controller pattern which is what Laravel uses.  It expects all traffic to come in through its index file and Laravel decides what controllers and functions to use depending on what you have setup in the routes file.  You would never want to access a file directly like that, everything needs to go through the index file.  It's really a different way of thinking than what you are probably used to in the C++ world so it might seem pretty foreign.

Comment: Thanks for replies! 
In that case, what steps should I take to debug two files in this scenario: Both files contain single class. One class uses functionality of the other. The best I came up with is to write 'unit test' for the class in each file and use simulated instead of data provided by other class as intended.